# Explain a bitshift assignment

Tags: javascript, java

I have a problem with this piece of code, can someone solve this for me?

```
a=32, b=0xE
```

I need explanation of "case 2":

```
case 2: b>>=(a>>5); break;
```

Comment: What part do you need explained?

Comment: Please give a more complete description of the question :)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
void main(){
int i, a = 1, b = 0xE;
for(i=5;i>=0;i--){
switch(i){
case 0: if(a==2^5) { a+=1; a/=b; }
case 1: printf("%d %d ", a, b);
case 2: b>>=(a>>5); break;
case 4: a+=1; a<<=1; break;
case 5:a |= b;
default:printf("%d ", a+1);
}
}
}
Before case 2 ,i got a=32,b is same 0xE, I need solution for case 2 ??

Comment: Which programming language is this exactly? You've tagged this question with the java and javascript tags (both completely different languages) and then your comment mentions stdio.h which suggests that you're using a language such as C or C++ which are different languages again.

Comment: Javascript or Java??

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `0xE` is a hexadecimal notation for `14` Now as per your problem
`b >>= (a>>5)` and `a = 32; b = 14;`
using right-shift operator(>>) 
`b = b >> (a >> 5)`
then
`b = 14 >> (32 >> 5)`
then
`b = 14 >> 1`
then
`b = 7`

Answer (score 1):

`case 2` is a bitwise shift with assignment.

```
b >>= (a>>5);
```

is

```
b = b >> (a >> 5);
```

**is**

```
b = b >> (a / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2);
```

And you can expand the right-shift by `a` to division by `2` as well.

Comment: Surely a right bit shift is a divide by two?

Comment: @JoeC I may have just finished cutting the grass. And I may have just finished a beer or two. Thanks.

Comment: I need to shift 32, 5 byte right. What is (a * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2) ?

Comment: @IvanHadzi-Cenic That would have been left-shifts.

Comment: I got 0 yero like solution ? is that right? how i can go further ? What is solution  for b=b>>0 ?

Comment: @IvanHadzi-Cenic `b = b>>0` is `b = b`